# I need to find the values in one column given the three minimum values of another column

Tags: r

I have a data set  *data1* and I need to find the min values in one column *pph* and find out what value they correspond to in another column *state*, which is column 1

this is what i have

```
data1[which.min(data1$pph), 1]
```

this gives me the minimum value and what it corresponds to in the first column, but I cannot figure out how to find the three most minimum values and what they correspond to.

Comment: Try `which(data1$pph == min(data1$pph))` instead

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using `slice_min()` from the dplyr library.

```
# making fake data
data1 <- data.frame("pph" = c(1:10), "state" = c(rep(c(1,2),5)))

# find min 3 pph but only show state column
data1 %>% slice_min(pph, n = 3) %>% select(state)
```

You can also assign the output of the dplyr pipeline to a variable if you need to.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you for the knowledge

Comment: No problem! Good luck and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `base` you can try

```
data1[order(data1$pph)[1:3],"state"]
```

Using `data.table` you can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)
data1[order(pph)[1:3],"state"]#Here you actually call the three most minimum values
```

Or similarly

```
data1[order(pph),"state"][1:3] #Here is like you filter the three most minimum values
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
data1 %>%
    filter(pph == min(pph))
```

Comment: I am not sure you obtain the three most minimum values with this though.